# How can subprocess.call() run as super user when the script wasn't run as super user?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I wrote the following code fully expecting it to raise an exception when I tried to run it. `reboot` must be run as super-user, and the way in which I was expecting to run this script was from a non-root context and without the use of sudo. (*user `pi` on my Raspberry Pi*)

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["sudo", "reboot"])
```

However, to my surprise, the above lines do indeed reboot my system, even when the script is run without sudo, in a non-root shell. How does this work?

**EDIT:**

```sh
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for pi on [HOSTNAME]:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin,
    env_keep+=NO_AT_BRIDGE

User pi may run the following commands on [HOSTNAME]:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -l` ?

Comment: See above, @wim. I see the `(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` line... is that what you're referring to?

Comment: The whole point of the `sudo` command is to allow ordinary users to run commands as super user. This has nothing to do with Python, it would work if the user just typed `sudo reboot` by hand.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that, but usually `sudo` requires the user to retype their password for the first time in any given session. Why doesn't that prevent the command from executing?

Comment: Well there's your answer.  `User pi may run the following commands ... (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL.`  i.e. that's how your system is configured

Comment: @ifconfig `NOPASSWD: ALL` means they can run commands without typing a password.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see now. Thanks for your kind explanations!

Comment: Basically that's why we need to use a dummy user like 1000 or create another user for some daemon program. These users won't even have sudo permission.

Comment: I didn't know that, @Sraw. It makes sense, now that I think about it.